# Excel Index formula for 3 column lookup

Tags: excel

I'm looking to look up 2 values on another worksheet and return a third column value in a cell.

It doesn't appear to like the bracket after Match containing the array.

```
=INDEX(Table9[@[Date of Last Review]], MATCH([@Name]&'Hot Water Safety'!G1, Table9[@Name]&Table9[@[Risk Assessment or Other Document Title]], 0))
```

I've also tried this without table referencing using the worksheet reference instead.

Comment: Never mind. Solved.

=INDEX('Risk Assessments'!F:F, MATCH([@Name]&G4, 'Risk Assessments'!A:A&'Risk Assessments'!D:D, 0))

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question and then accept it to close the question.

Comment: and whenever possible please provide some sample data with expected outcome.